# Call to helper of module not change the Mage_ prexif by my module prefix

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, helper

I have changed my `etc/system.xml` and my `etc/config.xml` with the structure which should replace the `Mage_JaviNewListProductController_Helper_Data` by `Lecasa_JaviNewListProductController_Helper_Data`.

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_JaviNewListProductController_Helper_Data' not
>   found in /home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/clon_lecasa/app/Mage.php on
>   line 547

[image: This is the system.xml file]

[image: This is the config.xml file]

[image: And this is the data helper of my module]

I do not know what more I can change for replace the Mage_ by the parent name of my module when I use:

```
Mage::helper('JaviNewListProductController')->renderProductInCatalog($_product);
```

I think that this has not relevance but I am using this function in rwd/default/template/.../list.phtml

[image: Active module]
Thanks

Comment: check your upper-lowercase-writing, that's inconsitsent. `Mage::helper('javinewlistproductcontroller')` should be correct in my opinion

Comment: try `Mage::helper('javinewlistproductcontroller')->renderProductInCatalog($_product);`

Comment: @Zefiryn I have replace it by lowercase but the error is the same. The issue here is the Mage_ prefix. I would like to read more of your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @HelgeB thanks for your answer, but the Mage_ prefix continues appearing. I have change it to lowercase, but I think that the problem is with some element of the configuratios. I wait for another suggestion. Thanks..

Comment: Is your module enabled (i.e. xml file in etc/modules and tag active true)?

Comment: `Mage_` prefix added to the helper class is always caused by incorrect configuration, you either uses incorrect name, made a typo in helper class configuration or incorrectly enabling module in `app/etc/modules`. Clear your cache, double check if names does not have typos.

Comment: @Zefiryn, I have modify all names using the magento standar but it continues returning this error. I have another question like alternative. If I put the current function on foldermodule/module/Block/Catalog/Product/List.php, is possible to call a function of this file from rwd/default/template/.../product/list.phtml? If it is possible, how can I call it? Thanks

Comment: @Javi Torre Sustaeta: did you check if the module is enabled? In yor screenshots there is nothing to see about a corresponding xml file in /etc/modules. The Mage_ prefix looks like Magento can't locate your module

Comment: @HelgeB Yes, it is active. I uploaded an image with this file. The module in backend is enabled.

Comment: You have Upper/Lowercase inconsistency in your config.xml vs. xml in /etc/modules. You shoud use the same notation in both files

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion in the comments you have to change the following in order to get your code working:

File `/etc/modules/Lecasa_Javinewlistproductcontroller.xml` must have this content (the tag below `<modules>` has to be identical with that used in `config.xml` and should correspond with the naming of the path to your modules folder if you replace `_` with `/`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lecasa_JaviNewListProductController>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lecasa_JaviNewListProductController>
    </modules>
</config>
```

With this done your module will be found by Magento and you can access the helper'S method with:

`Mage::helper('javinewlistproductcontroller')->renderProductInCatalog($_product);`

The identifier for your helper is the tag name below `<helpers>` in your `config.xml`.

I hope that will help you to get your module work.